# C# occasionally indexed cookies aren't saved and return original values after writing

Tags: c#, cookies

I have an application that reads and writes cookies in C#.  Sometimes the cookies are read or written and shared by an ASP classic page.  When classic writes something like course_int it actually is stored as course%5Fint.  So, when I'm reading or writing in C# .Net, I convert all underscores to %5F and things work well... most of the time.  Occasionally, cookie values get "stuck" and cannot be changed... even if I read them and write them in .Net and make sure asp classic hasn't touched them.  I wrote a test program to read a cookie, display, set a value, display.  The result is:

### 54

99

However, I run it a second time without doing anything but refreshing the page and I get the exact same output... like it was never written even though in the debugger, I can see it was.  Code looks like this:

In the .aspx

```
        <%=course_int %><br />
        <hr />
        <%=course_int1 %><br />
```

In the codebehind:

```
    course_int = getCookieValue("course_int");
    setCookieValue("course_int", "99");
    course_int1 = getCookieValue("course_int");

    public static string getCookieValue(string CookieName)
    {
        string CookieValue = "";
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["LS"];
            CookieName = CookieName.Replace("_", "%5F");
            if (cookie.Values[CookieName] != null)
            {
                CookieValue = cookie.Values[CookieName];
            }
        }
        return CookieValue;


    public static void setCookieValue(string CookieName, string CookieValue)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie;
        string NetCookieName = CookieName.Replace("_", "%5F");
        cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["LS"];

        if ( CookieValue == "")
        {
            cookie.Values.Remove(NetCookieName);
        }
        else
        {
            if (cookie.Values[NetCookieName] == null)
            {
                cookie.Values.Add(NetCookieName, CookieValue);
            }
            else
            {
                cookie.Values.Set(NetCookieName, CookieValue);
            }
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Set(cookie); (a post suggested this too)
        (also tried deleting and adding, no difference)
```

When I look at the actual cookie.Value it is:

ReturnXT=&site%5Fname=&thm=131&LMW=1&btnFA=%2377AAD7&btnC=%232E7CC1&hovC=%234C619C&pagF=%2320252b&bill%265Fdate=&lesson%265Fint=&test%5Fint=37&DOG=1&MP=1&jcLimited=&company=ALL&mnuF=%23000000&part=&0=1&lesson%5Fint=0&lng=&site%5Fparam=&ADM=0&PAI=1&DT=&org%5Fint=131&ocode=&MLC=&manager=&site%5Fregion=0&site%5Fint=2&site%5Fkey=%40Default&pmsg=1&perm=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C6%2C10&btnF=%23ffffff&hovF=%23ffffff&PII=1&test%265Fint=&ReturnX=https%3A%2F%2Fhobart%2Elearn%2Enet%2Flmw%2F&lesson%5Fname=&cld=&hmLoc=https%3A%2F%2Fhobart%2Elearn%2Enet%3A443%2FDefault%2Easp&limit%5Fparam=&pcode=No+Department&dept=&person%5Fid=stever&person%5Fint=3&xorg=&pagC=%23ffffff&EAI=1&lmt3=1&ord%265Fdate=&guide%265Fseq=&NB%5F3%5F54=&course%5Fname=BloodbornePathogensv3PS4eLessonCopy

&course%5Fint=99 &dhm=C%3A%5Cinetpub%5C&ED=&person%5Fname=Steve+Ricketts&h1=%2320252b&PCI=1
&course%265Fint=&question%265Fint=&ord%5Fdate=&bill%5Fdate=&question%5Fint=&guide%5Fseq=0&root=%2Flmw%2F

&EH=&person%5Fkey=stever&G2T=&myTM=0&mnuC=%
23efefef&DS=video%2FvideoSelection%2Easp%3FDT%3D1%26SM%3DASGN%26bUn%3D1%26bLng%3D1&schedule%265Fdate=&schedule%5Fdate=

Obviously, I've separated them at the course_int so you can see more easily.  Odd thing, there is a &course%265Fint too... Not sure what's that's all about.  I've tried deleting the entire cookie, setting the cookie, adding it.  All combinations I can think of.

So, I'm sure I'm missing something... it writes the 99 but the next time it reads, it's still 54. This is Server 2019 but also happens on 2008 and 2016.   What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was getting another domain in the cookie so I had a path of / and a path of /lmw both with similar values.  Apparently, I could change one but not the other.  I couldn't delete the /lmw domain without deleting all cookies so I did an AJAX call to a page that just cleared the /lmw domain cookie and that worked.  I was able to read/write cookies again.